# How to get rid of annoying "mydb" schema from workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Whenever I try to reverse engineer using [mySQL workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) an empty "mydb" schema appears.

No matter how hard I try to remove it it keeps reappearing.

- How can I get rid of it completely without it ever re-appearing?
- Why does it keep reappearing?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;
  commit;
```

To drop the schema totally

Answer (score 0):

Use the context menu on the model overview page:

[image]

Comment: Tried this as well. Heck I've tried all tricks in the box. Seems like a workbench bug